How to set physics body correctly to accommodate custom pivot in SceneKit
I need to set the physics body of a node. When I have a custom pivot but without scales or rotation, I can simply transform the shape by the inverse of the pivot, like this:
    let boxGeo = SCNBox(width: 5, height: 5, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
    let box = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeo)
    rootNode.addChildNode(box)

    // i have a custom pivot here: 
    box.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(1, 1, 1)
    
    // i can simply transform the shape by inverse of pivot:
    let boxPhysicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: box.geometry!)
      .transformed(by: SCNMatrix4Invert(box.pivot))
    box.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: boxPhysicsShape)

Note that transformed(by:) is a helper function that I provide below:

public extension SCNPhysicsShape {
  
  func transformed(by transform: SCNMatrix4) -> SCNPhysicsShape {
    return SCNPhysicsShape(
      shapes: [self],
      transforms: [NSValue(scnMatrix4: transform)])
  }

  func translated(by translation: SCNVector3) -> SCNPhysicsShape {
    let transform = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
    return transformed(by: transform)
  }
  
  func scaled(by scale: SCNVector3) -> SCNPhysicsShape {
    let transform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z)
    return transformed(by: transform)
  }
  
  func rotated(by rotation: SCNVector4) -> SCNPhysicsShape {
    let transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(rotation.w, rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z)
    return transformed(by: transform)
  }
  
}

This works fine. However, when the node is scaled, this won't work anymore:
    // ...
    box.scale = SCNVector3Make(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)
    box.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(1, 1, 1)

    // ...
    let boxPhysicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: box.geometry!)
      .scaled(by: box.scale)
      .transformed(by: SCNMatrix4Invert(box.pivot))

If you turn on the showPhysicsShapes debug option, the physics shape is misaligned.
Similar to scale, when there's rotation involved, I can't align the physics shape either.
Here's a minimum repro code you can play around:
class My3DScene: SCNScene {
  override init() {
    super.init()
    
    let camera = SCNCamera()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 50)
    rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    
    let boxGeo = SCNBox(width: 5, height: 5, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
    boxGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    let box = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeo)
    box.scale = SCNVector3Make(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)
    box.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(1, 2, 3)
    box.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(1, 1, 1)
    rootNode.addChildNode(box)
    
    let boxPhysicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: box.geometry!)
      // no need to rotate, shape is rotated by node automatically
      .scaled(by: box.scale)
      .transformed(by: SCNMatrix4Invert(box.pivot))
    box.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: boxPhysicsShape)
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}


class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
      
      let scnView = SCNView(frame: self.view.frame)
      scnView.debugOptions = .showPhysicsShapes
      
      self.view.addSubview(scnView)
      let scene = My3DScene()
      scnView.present(scene, with: .fade(withDuration: 1), incomingPointOfView: nil)
   }
}


public extension SCNPhysicsShape {
  
  func transformed(by transform: SCNMatrix4) -> SCNPhysicsShape {
    return SCNPhysicsShape(
      shapes: [self],
      transforms: [NSValue(scnMatrix4: transform)])
  }

  func translated(by translation: SCNVector3) -> SCNPhysicsShape {
    let transform = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
    return transformed(by: transform)
  }
  
  func scaled(by scale: SCNVector3) -> SCNPhysicsShape {
    let transform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z)
    return transformed(by: transform)
  }
  
  func rotated(by rotation: SCNVector4) -> SCNPhysicsShape {
    let transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(rotation.w, rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z)
    return transformed(by: transform)
  }
  
}


You're encountering an issue where the physics shape isn't aligning correctly when the node is scaled and rotated. This is because SCNPhysicsShape doesn't automatically take the node's scale, rotation, and pivot into account when creating the shape for the physics body. Your current approach works for non-transformed shapes, but with scaling or rotation applied, this causes misalignment.
To solve this, you need to apply the node's full transformation (including scale, rotation, and pivot) to the physics shape. Instead of just scaling and translating the physics shape, you'll need to apply the full transformation matrix that includes the scale, rotation, and pivot adjustment.
Solution:

Compute the full transformation of the node: This includes its scale, rotation, and pivot.

Transform the physics shape using this full transformation.


Check below updated code.
class My3DScene: SCNScene {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        let camera = SCNCamera()
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 50)
        rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        
        let boxGeo = SCNBox(width: 5, height: 5, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
        boxGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        let box = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeo)
        
        // Set scale, rotation, and pivot
        box.scale = SCNVector3Make(1.5, 1.5, 1.5)
        box.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(1, 2, 3)
        box.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(1, 1, 1)
        
        rootNode.addChildNode(box)
        
        // Create the physics shape and transform it with the node's full transformation
        let boxPhysicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: box.geometry!)
        
        // Apply the full transform: scale, rotation, and pivot
        let nodeTransformation = box.worldTransform
        
        // Apply the full transformation to the physics shape
        let transformedShape = boxPhysicsShape.transformed(by: nodeTransformation)
        
        // Set the physics body
        box.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: transformedShape)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let scnView = SCNView(frame: self.view.frame)
        scnView.debugOptions = .showPhysicsShapes
        
        self.view.addSubview(scnView)
        let scene = My3DScene()
        scnView.present(scene, with: .fade(withDuration: 1), incomingPointOfView: nil)
    }
}


This doesn't align up my nodes - You can't apply the rotation part of the transform, because the shape rotated together with the node itself.
